# Are 3-terminal capacitors non-polarized?

Tags: bypass-capacitor

Are 3-terminal capacitors, such as [YFF18AC1C104MT0Y0N](https://product.tdk.com/system/files/dam/doc/product/emc/emc/3tf/catalog/3tf_automotive_general_yff-ac_en.pdf), non-polarized?
And/or are they generally ok to use for decoupling bipolar op-amps?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those are ceramic capacitors, so will be non-polarized.

There is only one capacitor in the package.

They are feed-through capacitors - the end terminals are connected together and to one side of the capacitor, while the other side if the capacitor is connected to the center terminal which is intended to be grounded.

They could be used for decoupling, but you would need two if you have bipolar supplies.  As I read your question, you are considering using one of these parts to decouple both positive and negative supplies of an op-amp - this won't work as they have a short circuit between the end terminals.

Comment: Thank you Peter. No, I was not considering using only one for both rails. I assumed two, and was asking for the negative side. Poorly worded on my part. Just wanted confirmation, which you provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Peter's answer:

There are also similarly looking X2Y caps, which indeed have 3 different logical terminals. These could be used in principle to decouple two supply voltages to ground, but then again, so could two regular capacitors, which are cheaper to buy and cheaper to place because they are in your BOM already.

The main advantage of X2Y is not for decoupling several supplies but for a single supply at very high frequency such as GHz due to ESL advantages.

Comment: Good info, thanks!